# HFP implementation for Android

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-bluetooth, hfp

I want to implement HFP in Bluetooth for Android Marshmallow . Can anyone share the related document or provide me your guidance

Comment: Did you get any help? Share some info if you have any.

Comment: @Karthikeyan if you got this solution, so please share here too, i am also looking for connect HFP profile bluetooth via Android app.

Comment: That work carried by another person. Sorry guys

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried to implement HFP or rather control HFP via an android app. The thing is HFP public api is hidden and you [only get methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html) to get connected devices, connection states etc. and the connections is handled automatically. But if you want to get access to the hidden APIs, with which you could connect/disconnect HFP profile and get another set of features, you would need to use java method of reflections. You can [use this android things code](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-audio/blob/master/audio-sink/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/bluetooth/audio/A2dpSinkHelper.java) as a reference. Just refer to how they have implemented disconnect method in a2dp sink. For the hfp part I have only tried exposing connect and disconnect and nothing else. Also as far as I know, keep in mind that, google doesn't recommend using the hidden APIs and can withdraw them anytime so you need to keep a watch on the new releases. Hope this helps!